# IIS fails after upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10

The question is now moot as the customer re-installed IIS on Windows 10 and the issue went away.  I'll still leave it here for reference

---

I have a customer running an IIS based application I built years ago.  The system runs (ran) on a Windows 7 x64 system and all it (the IIS part) does is a basic website that is only available on the local host and does some CRUD type operations.

They recently updated the box to Windows 10 x64, and when they went to actually use the system today, they found it not working.  It appears to be an issue with IIS itself.  They sent me this entry from the event log:

> ISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE
>
> IIS Manager could not load
> type
> 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Features.SharedConfig.SharedConfigModuleProvider,
> Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' for module provider 'SharedConfig'
> that is declared in
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that
> the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module
> provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).
>
> Exception:System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Features.SharedConfig.SharedConfigModuleProvider'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.    at
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.Type.GetType(String typeName,
> Boolean throwOnError)    at
> Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.AdministrationModuleProvider.GetModuleProvider(String
> userName, String connectionName)

This appears to be similar to [IIS Manager could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Management](https://serverfault.com/q/787941/12255) but as I am a bit lost I am not sure if it is the same sort of thing.

I'm looking for some help to point out how to get past this error and to get IIS running again.

Comment: Could someone please explain the close vote

Comment: Start by building a new Windows 10 machine on your own and enable IIS on it. With a healthy machine aside, you can compare and learn what's wrong on that machine. The linked thread you talked about is totally irrelevant, as the exception message differs so much.

Comment: @LexLi Your comment does really help in my situation.  And IMHO the linked thread is at least partially relevant as the class of issue (IIS Manager could not load type) is teh same in both cases

Comment: it _might_ have helped to simply replace all occurences of `Version=7.0.0.0` with `Version=10.0.0.0` in `administration.config`. however - i would never upgrade IIS, always fresh install.